# Как клонировать репозиторий и работать в ветке, в которой работал ранее

Tags: git

Моя работа над проектом остановилась на commit некоторых изменений в ветку feature/renderFilters. Далее я запушил изменения в одноименную ветку в удаленном репо. По некоторым причинам мне было необходимо удалить свой проект. Теперь я клонировал его, но я нахожусь в ветке *main и вижу только ее, когда делаю `git branch`. Мне надо продолжить работу в ветке feature/renderFilters. Скажите, как правильно это сделать, чтобы увидеть у себя последний коммит этой ветки, продолжить работу и запушить изменения в нее же на сервере.

Answer (score 1):

После клонирования репозитория для просмотра всех веток, в том числе удаленных, нужно было выполнить команду

```
git branch -a
```

Удаленные ветки по умолчанию будут отображаться красным цветом.

Далее выполним команду

```
git checkout --track ссылка_на_удаленный_репозиторий/имя_ветки
```

В итоге Вы перейдете на вновь созданную локальную ветку, следящую за удаленной.

Ссылка на удаленный репозиторий по умолчанию имеет имя `origin`

Последний коммит ветки можно посмотреть так

```
git log -1
```

Лично мне такой вариант отображения коммитов не очень нравится. Я настраиваю алиас для отображения графа, автора коммита, даты коммита и т.д. Но это уже совсем другая история :)

Comment: Разве дефолтный `git log -1` не показывает автора и дату? И зачем отображение графа, если смотрим один коммит?

Comment: Согласен, крайний абзац тут лишний, не по теме. А в целом алиас для лога в одну строку и с графом удобен в использовании. Если еще добавить разные цвета для имени коммита, автора, даты, ветки, то читать такой лог гораздо удобнее дефолтного.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение -

```
git checkout feature/renderFilters
```